# Correct icon sizes for launch screen

Tags: ios, xcode

Following from njuri's response below, I have added a new image asset and placed within it three images: 200 x1, 400 x2, and 600 x3 (please see image below):
[Launch Screen in Xcode for Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172508/launch-screen-in-xcode-for-swift/34172555#34172555)

[image]

Is this correct? I wasn't sure if you meant 200 x1, 400 x2 and 600 x3 or 200 x1, x2, x3; 400 x1, x2, x3; 600 x1, x2, x3 (in other words 3 images or 9 images).

Also, I have the 'Universal' box checked. Is that correct?

Thanks.

Comment: ??? kind of a cryptic question

Answer (score 1):

[image: Expected Size]

When working with asset catalogs select the placeholder for the asset you will be using and the inspector on the far right bottom will tell you what the expected size. Repeat this for every image you intend to use to find out the size you need.